# CentOS CUPS Configuration

Tags: centos, cups

I have a question about configuring CUPS for CentOS. I have CUPS installed on CentOS in one machine, and I am trying to access the web interface of CUPS from a different machine. The machine with CentOS and CUPS have an IP of 10.0.0.1, and the second machine have an IP of 10.0.0.2. I have a network printer set up with an IP of 10.0.0.10 and both machine can ping the printer. But the second machine cannot access the CentOS machine via web interface.

Below is part of my cupsd.conf file:

```
SystemGroup sys root

Listen *:631
Browsing On
BrowseOrder allow,deny
BrowseAllow all
BrowseAddress 10.0.0.2:631

<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 10.0.0.2
</Location>

<Location /admin>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 10.0.0.2
</Location>

<Location /admin/conf>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 10.0.0.2
</Location>
```

I also read somewhere that CUPS for CentOS requires SSL Certificate, is that true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUPS does not require the SSL certificate. You can disable the https by adding `DefaultEncryption Never` to the config file and restarting the daemon. In recent versions of CentOS (you didn't specify the version you're running), there's an "Allow remote administration" checkbox in the web interface that will provide remote CUPS admin page access on port 631. In your case, browse to: https://10.0.0.1:631/admin

Here's the standard CUPS file I tend to deploy on new systems.

```
MaxLogSize 2000000000
LogLevel info
SystemGroup sys root
# Allow remote access
Port 631
Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock
# Disable printer sharing and shared printers.
Browsing Off
DefaultAuthType Basic
<Location />
  Allow ALL
  Allow all
  # Allow remote administration...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
<Location /admin>
  Allow ALL
  Allow all
  # Allow remote administration...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
<Location /admin/conf>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  Allow ALL
  Allow all
  # Allow remote access to the configuration files...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
<Policy default>
  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job CUPS-Move-Job>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>
DefaultEncryption Never
```